# How to limit pagination?

Tags: pagination, cakephp-1.3

I have a problem with this pagination i use this code

```
var $paginate = array(
    'limit' => 5)
```

yes it work but after i code my search plugin, this pagination code is not working

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as an example for your pagination

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'conditions' => array( ... )
    'limit' => 5,
);
$myResults = $this->paginate( 'MyModel' );
```